# Change server side cached variable from outside of website?

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server-2016

I'm playing with laravel/php and was using the Cache to store a specific cached variable.  I wanted to avoid hitting the database for a property / setting I need all my users to rely on.  This setting controls whether certain events can occur.  This wasnt difficult as I could simply check if I have the cached variable and assign it otherwise get it from my backend (SQL Server):

```
if (Cache::has('myKey')){
   $value = Cache::get('myKey');
} else {
   $value = DB::table('myTable')->get();
   Cache::put('myKey', $value);
} 
//use cached value...
```

This cached value or db setting is caused by a certain action of an administrator he / she can turn this setting on (true) or off (false).  However, we also have an outside process (not on the actual site but an actual sql job) that has to also set this setting.  In the SQL job I can easily assign the db setting (true or false) but how do I write that setting to my cached value in laravel / php if I am inside of my sql job?

**The short of this is how can I set a server side cached variable value from outside of my website?**

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your question, but if you want to "change the data structure in a remote server", you should expose an API to do so yourself. Otherwise, if you know you are using Redis for caching, you can ssh into the Redis instance and change the cache yourself.

Comment: @DanielCheung - I simply want to change a server side cached variable from a certain value (true) to another value (false) outside my website - just as I have clearly explained from my question.

Comment: Yes, so in that case I would either go with exposing a REST API (protected by authentication of course) that does this. Something like `http://my-host/api/clear-cache`. Or ssh into the server directly and change my cache.

Comment: @DanielCheung - makes sense and seems simple not sure where my brain went this morning.  Thanks please add as an answer so you earn the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in that case I would either go with exposing a REST API (protected by authentication of course) that does this. Something like `http://my-host/api/clear-cache`.

Or ssh into the server directly and change the cache.